# Flutter: how to use 'generic' class constructor?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to create a 'generic' class constructor so that instead of (which is not re-usable with other classes):

**uploader.dart:**

```
class Uploader extends StatefulWidget {
  const Uploader({
    Key key,
      @required this.event
    }) : super(key: key);
      final Event event;

    ...

    uploadEvent() async {
        await database.setEvent(widget.event)
```

**database.dart:**

```
Future<void> setEvent(Event event) async => await _service.setData(
    data: event.toMap(),
    docId: event.id,
  );
```

It becomes something like:

**uploader.dart:**

```
class Uploader extends StatefulWidget {
  const Uploader({
    Key key,
      @required this.event
    }) : super(key: key);
      final T class;

    ...

    uploadEvent() async {
        await database.setGeneric(widget.generic)
```

**database.dart:**

```
Future<void> setGeneric(T generic) async => await _service.setData(
    data: generic.toMap(),
    docId: generic.id,
  );
```

Is it possible to do something like that? And what would the correct terminology for that be (so that I can update the question accordingly)?

The other option is passing event.toMap() to "final Map generic" in uploader.dart, but I feel that there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

T is not subtype an object that has a method `toMap()`.

u let it `extends` a `class` with method `onMap()`

```
abstract class Base{
  toMap();
}

Future<void> setGeneric<T extends Base>(T generic) async => await _service.setData(
    data: generic.toMap(),
    docId: generic.id,
  );
```